# Public API for sending messages (asyncore, Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, asyncore

How do I create a public API for sending messages?

Let's say I have a connection that requires me to send a login message first, or maybe I wanna process some data and send a new message to server. How do I do that? Is this possible to do with asyncore?

Maybe the better question is how do I interact with this asyncore loop after starting it?

This is my attempt at doing something like this:

```py
# package.coreio
import asyncore
from queue import Queue

class Client(asyncore.dispatcher):
    """This class represents a client to server connection."""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._host = ...
        self._port = ...

        self._messages = Queue()

        self.create_socket()
        self.connect((self._host, self._port))

    def send_message(self, message: bytes) -> None:
        """A public API for sending messages to the server."""
        self._messages.put(message)

    def writable(self) -> None:
        return not self._messages.empty()

    def handle_write(self) -> None:
        message = self._messages.get()
        self.send(message)
        print('Sending:', message)

    def handle_read(self) -> None:
        data = self.recv(4096)
        print(data)
```

This is my attempt at using this interface:

```py
import asyncore
import threading
import time

from .coreio import Client

login_message = ...
get_port = ...

client = Client()
client.send_message(login_message)

thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncore.loop)
thread.start()

time.sleep(2.5)  # Do something for 2.5 seconds.
client.send_message(get_port)  # Send another message.
```

Obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: I think a simpler approach would be to keep the asyncore loop in the main thread and do blocking tasks in another threads. The important question is: why aren't you using asyncio instead?

Comment: @xyres I don't understand why it doesn't work. This code makes perfect sense to me. I've decided to use some high-level interface (after trying to implement this with simple sockets, threads, and a lot of callbacks) for my application and asyncore made perfect sense until now. I guess I could use asyncio instead.